# TensorFlow convolutional neural network using higher resolution images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I've been following some TensorFlow tutorials for convolutional neural networks for a while and everything has been going fine whilst using the test sets used for the examples, however when I try to move on to using my own labelled data, things seem to stop working.

The images I have are 700x700 px images, so after changing some small things in the script I can get the training to start, however the accuracies never seem to update from the starting value (see below).

[image: Training run using 700x700 px images.]

I have a total of around 800 images, so I would understand if the model was overfitting but not updating at all seems odd.

The code I use is below.

I've also found that if I split the images up into smaller images of around 140x140 px the script is able to train fine, so my guess would be that it's a memory issue. But I would have expected that if this were the case it would come back with an error rather than just not training?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import os
import random
from shutil import copyfile
import time

device = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(f'Running on device: {device}')

def create_train_val_dirs(root_path):
    """
    Creates directories for the train and test sets
    
    Args:
        root_path (string) - the base directory path to create subdirectories from
    
    Returns:
        None
    """ 

    os.makedirs(root_path)

    val_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'validation')
    train_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'training')
    os.makedirs(train_path)
    os.makedirs(val_path)

    os.makedirs(os.path.join(val_path, 'Good'))
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(val_path, 'Bad'))
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(train_path, 'Good'))
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(train_path, 'Bad'))

def split_data(SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_DIR, VALIDATION_DIR, SPLIT_SIZE):

    """
    Splits the data into train and test sets
    
    Args:
        SOURCE_DIR (string): directory path containing the images
        TRAINING_DIR (string): directory path to be used for training
        VALIDATION_DIR (string): directory path to be used for validation
        SPLIT_SIZE (float): proportion of the dataset to be used for training
        
    Returns:
        None
    """
    

    im_list = random.sample(os.listdir(SOURCE_DIR), len(os.listdir(SOURCE_DIR)))

    for index, im in enumerate(im_list):
        if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, im)) == 0:
            print(f"{im} is zero length, so ignoring.")
            continue
        if index <= SPLIT_SIZE*len(im_list):
            copyfile(os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, im), os.path.join(TRAINING_DIR, im))
        else:
            copyfile(os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, im), os.path.join(VALIDATION_DIR, im))

def train_val_generators(TRAINING_DIR, VALIDATION_DIR, batch_size, input_size):
    """
    Creates the training and validation data generators
  
    Args:
        TRAINING_DIR (string): directory path containing the training images
        VALIDATION_DIR (string): directory path containing the testing/validation images
        batch_size (integer): Integer number of batches (amount of images trained per loop).
        input_size (tensor: (int, int)): Tensor containing the size of the input image, or 
        preferred input size (if different to the actual size it will be scaled). 
    
    Returns:
        train_generator, validation_generator - tuple containing the generators
    """

    # Instantiate the ImageDataGenerator class (don't forget to set the arguments to augment the images)
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.0,
                                    #  rotation_range=90,           #Turned off since it wasn't on previously
                                    #  width_shift_range=0.2,
                                    #  height_shift_range=0.2,
                                    #  shear_range=0.2,
                                    #  zoom_range=0.2,
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    vertical_flip=True,
                                    #  fill_mode='nearest'
                                    )

    # Pass in the appropriate arguments to the flow_from_directory method
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=TRAINING_DIR,
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        class_mode='binary',
                                                        target_size=target_size,
                                                        color_mode= 'grayscale')

    # Instantiate the ImageDataGenerator class (don't forget to set the rescale argument)
    validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.0)

    # Pass in the appropriate arguments to the flow_from_directory method
    validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=VALIDATION_DIR,
                                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                class_mode='binary',
                                                                target_size=target_size,
                                                                color_mode= 'grayscale')
    ### END CODE HERE
    return train_generator, validation_generator


# Find the start time
initial_t = time.perf_counter()

# set tf_xla_enable_xla_devices flags
os.environ['TF_XLA_FLAGS'] = '--tf_xla_enable_xla_devices'
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'

# Define paths
SSD_DIR = Path(os.getcwd())
DATA_DIR = SSD_DIR.joinpath(r'Python_scripts\Machine_Learning\Si111\Tensorflow\Dataset\Binary_notc\all\No_splitting')
SOURCE_DIR = DATA_DIR.joinpath('Input_data')
ROOT_DIR = DATA_DIR.joinpath('ForRuns')

GOOD_SOURCE_DIR = SOURCE_DIR.joinpath("Good")
BAD_SOURCE_DIR = SOURCE_DIR.joinpath("Bad")

TRAINING_DIR = ROOT_DIR.joinpath('training')
VALIDATION_DIR = ROOT_DIR.joinpath('validation')

TRAINING_GOOD_DIR = TRAINING_DIR.joinpath("Good")
VALIDATION_GOOD_DIR = VALIDATION_DIR.joinpath("Good")

TRAINING_BAD_DIR = TRAINING_DIR.joinpath("Bad")
VALIDATION_BAD_DIR = VALIDATION_DIR.joinpath("Bad")

try:
  create_train_val_dirs(root_path=ROOT_DIR)
  print(f'Creating directory at {ROOT_DIR}...')
except FileExistsError:
  print(f"{ROOT_DIR} already exists.")

# Empty directories in case you run this cell multiple times
if len(os.listdir(TRAINING_BAD_DIR)) > 0:
    for file in os.listdir(TRAINING_BAD_DIR):
        os.remove(TRAINING_BAD_DIR.joinpath(file))
if len(os.listdir(TRAINING_GOOD_DIR)) > 0:
    for file in os.listdir(TRAINING_GOOD_DIR):
        os.remove(TRAINING_GOOD_DIR.joinpath(file))
if len(os.listdir(VALIDATION_BAD_DIR)) > 0:
    for file in os.listdir(VALIDATION_BAD_DIR):
        os.remove(VALIDATION_BAD_DIR.joinpath(file))
if len(os.listdir(VALIDATION_GOOD_DIR)) > 0:
    for file in os.listdir(VALIDATION_GOOD_DIR):
        os.remove(VALIDATION_GOOD_DIR.joinpath(file))

# Define proportion of images used for training
split_size = .9

# Run the function
# NOTE: Messages about zero length images should be printed out
split_data(GOOD_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_GOOD_DIR, VALIDATION_GOOD_DIR, split_size)
split_data(BAD_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_BAD_DIR, VALIDATION_BAD_DIR, split_size)

batch_size = 5
target_size = (700, 700)
epochs = 25
layers = 2
starting = 512

train_generator, validation_generator = train_val_generators(TRAINING_DIR, VALIDATION_DIR, batch_size=batch_size, input_size=target_size)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([ 
      
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(40, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape= (700,700,1)),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(80, (3,3), activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(160, (3,3), activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(320, (3,3), activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    #   tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    #   tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
  ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

# Begin training!
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=validation_generator)


# Find the final time (before plotting etc.)
def convert_to_preferred_format(sec):
   sec = sec % (24 * 3600)
   hour = sec // 3600
   sec %= 3600
   min = sec // 60
   sec %= 60
   return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hour, min, sec) 

final_t = time.perf_counter()

total_time = final_t - initial_t
print('*'*20)
print(f'Total time taken for training was {convert_to_preferred_format(total_time)}')
print('*'*20)

# Save the model, history and accuracy plot
save_name = f'AnotherAttempt'
Models_dir = SSD_DIR.joinpath('ML/Models/TensorFlow/Si(111)')

acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epoch_range = range(len(acc))

plt.plot(epoch_range, acc, 'r', label='Training accuracy')
plt.plot(epoch_range, val_acc, 'b', label='Validation accuracy')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend(loc=0)

plt.savefig(Models_dir.joinpath(f'acc_plots/No_splitting/{save_name}.png'))
model.save(Models_dir.joinpath(f'models/No_splitting/{save_name}.h5'))

# convert the history.history dict to a pandas DataFrame:     
hist_df = pd.DataFrame(history.history) 

# or save to csv: 
hist_csv_file = Models_dir.joinpath(f'histories/No_splitting/{save_name}.csv')
with open(hist_csv_file, mode='w') as f:
    hist_df.to_csv(f)

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
plt.close()
```

Comment: It's rather a problem with the model. With 700x700 images, you still will have a shape of about 43x43x320 just before the Flatten layer. Which seems pretty big

Comment: So I guess the solution would be to reduce the number of kernels in the convolutional layers/increase the number of layers total?

Comment: Please try again by adding the bigger kernels size(`5,5)` or `(7,7)` to convolve the large images efficiently. Also change the `batch_size=16`.  You can also check this link for [strategies to prevent overfitting](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#strategies_to_prevent_overfitting). Let us know if the issue still persists.